# CrudRepository existsBy returns a wrong result

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I faced the following problem: A `CrudRepository` returns a wrong result that is not matches database data. 
There is an entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTRIBUTE")
public class Attribute implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7360594743377794716L;
  *******

  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;  
  *******
  @Column(name = "R_ORGANIZATION_ID")
  private Long refOrganizationId;  
  @Column(name = "TEXT_CODE")
  private String textCode;
  *******
  /**
  getters, settrs, hashCode, etc
  **/
}
```

And I have an appropriate `CrudRepository`

```
public interface AttributeRepository
    extends CrudRepository<Attribute, Long> {
  *****

  boolean existsByTextCodeAndRefOrganizationId(String textCode, Long organizationId);

  *****
}
```

The problem is that the repository returns `true` for a data that is not in the DB.

For instance I am passing *'asdf'* as a `textCode` and *0* as an `organizationId`. And I'm geting `true` despite there is no such a `textCode` in the DB. 
Here is a autogenerated code of the query:

```
    select
        TOP(?) attribute0_.id as col_0_0_ 
    from
        attribute attribute0_ 
    where
        attribute0_.text_code=? 
        and attribute0_.r_organization_id=?
12:00:24.805 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [asdf]
12:00:24.805 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [0]
```

But if I run a query in any SQL manager I will get 0 rows. What can it be?

Stuff: `MS SQL Server 2012, Java 1.8, spring-boot.version 1.5.4.RELEASE`

Comment: Maybe records are created in transaction and then removed modified?

Comment: @talex there are no any create/update actions. only select.

Comment: Try to replace `exists...` by `get...` and log results. It may give you a clue about what data it finds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deep debugging showed me thet the problem was in the sequence of invocations of methods in the appropriate service. The main thing is that `existsBy` returns results taking into accout created entities that are not in the DB at the moment of the `existsBy` invocations. So at some steps before my problem the `Attribute` entity had been created. It means the `Attribute` has been created in the current transaction and not has been persisted yet but `existsBy` already has taken it as a part of the resultset.

Thank's everyone!

Comment: Check transaction isolation level.